# How to fix Insufficient Authorization in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I was working on a simple messaging app using Dana Mulder's tutorial at https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1#.xjhgikji4
However after being able to get a working system I realized that any user can see other user messages by playing around with the url.

For example users can iterate the number in this url http://localhost:3000/conversations/3/messages and see all other messages where they are not a part of. I was trying to add some protection without luck. Would anybody know how to fix the insufficient authorization issue for this application?  Thanks!.

Here is my conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :confirm_logged_in
  layout 'authenticated'

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end

  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end

  private
  def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end
end
```

Here is the messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  layout 'authenticated'
  before_action do
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

  def index
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    if @messages.length > 10
      @over_ten = true
      @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
    end
    if params[:m]
      @over_ten = false
      @messages = @conversation.messages
    end
    if @messages.last
      if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
        @messages.last.read = true;
      end
    end

    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def new
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
  end

  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in your model design, User has many conversions `current_user` is object represent currently logged-in user. You can limit conversation that he can view to only conversation that belong to him by this query:

```
@conversation = Conversation.where("(sender_id = ? OR recipient_id =?) AND id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id, params[:conversation_id]).first
```

instead of `@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])`, which will get any `Conversation` he passed into param `conversation_id`.

Comment: Thanks @Long Nguyen, yes I was using current_user. I tried your change in the messages controller by adding your code and removed the existing one but I got the following error message: undefined method `messages' for #<Conversation::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xba7d0b8>

Comment: @Zero updated. Please try again. Because `where` returns ActiveRecord Relation rather than the object (an array of found records), in this query we know that it will return at most one record so we will call `.first` to get that only record.